# Circular dependencies, need some help with exact code

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm relatively new to Android and I've stucked with the following problem. I have an xml layout code, which seems to be working on 1.5, but fails on 1.6 and further with Circular dependencies are not allowed with RelativeLayout.
I've googled some info on that error, and I got the basics. Still too few info about this topic.
I still can't figure, where exactly that circular dependences occur in my code.
Please, could some of you point me to the lines, where that happens, and explain why it so?

```
<LinearLayout  
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal">
    <ImageView
        android:paddingTop="3dip"
        android:id="@+id/typeicon"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>  
</LinearLayout>

<RelativeLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="6.5"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:paddingRight="20dip">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:id="@+id/toprellistlayout"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/trannumbertext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/summtext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_below="@id/toprellistlayout"
        android:id="@+id/maintranstext"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textSize="13sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
    />
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:layout_below="@id/maintranstext"
        android:id="@+id/toprellistlayout"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/datetext"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".3"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:text="01.01.0000 00:00:00"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/statusview"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight=".7"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/finlist_rejected"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/cross"
            android:drawablePadding="5dip"
            android:background="@android:id/empty"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="11sp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I would recommend developing for version 1.6 onwards. Take a look here(http://developer.android.com/resources/dashboard/platform-versions.html) for business reasons. From a technology standpoint there are a lot of changes from 1.5 to 1.6 and the API's are consistent from 1.6 onwards.

Comment: I dont have an IDE in front of me to render that out but at first glance those inner relativelayouts could probably be simple linearlayouts and just use gravity instead on the textviews.

Comment: Yeah, I'm developing for 1.6 and use libraries from it. But still I'm debugging as one of the emulators 1.5.
I'll rewrite the code to use linear layouts, but it is still interesting - where there are this circular dependencies are. For the general information. And maybe it helps someone else as well.

And yeah, all that code, provided above - is in Linear Layout itself, if it is important.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After an hour by partially deleting the lines, I've finally figured, where that "Circular dependencies" were.

It appears, that when SDK parses `RelativeLayout` xml, and positioning the items - it can't take, for example, the view C, which is below the view B, which is below the view A. If you look carefully - you'll find that part in my code.
The solution - is to make an additional `RelativeLayout`, in which to place the views C and B.