# Android layout_height doesn't wrap_content

Tags: android, layout

I have an XML Layout file looking like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toppane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottompane"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/genericbutton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/genericbutton" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/genericbutton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/genericbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>   
</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the bottompane to wrap its content on both the width and height.

Wrap_content on the bottompane works on the width (for a total of 100dp), but the wrap_content doesn't seem to work for the height. bottompane gets a height of the parent, so that the toppane isnt even visible.

Why is this happening? What am I missing or doing wrong?

EDIT: pictures will come soon. What i want to achieve, is the bottompanel having a height which simply wraps its contents. So no higher then the two buttons above each other (100dp), and the toppanel to fill up the rest of the space above the bottompane, all the way till it aligns on top with its parent.

EDIT2: [image http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9871/wrapcontent.png](http://img405.imageshack.us/img405/9871/wrapcontent.png)
the blue line is what the layout is, although the height is set to wrap_content. the red line is what it should be (just wrapping the content). the green line is how the toppane should be layed out (sticking to the top of the bottompane)

Comment: what you want to achieve add picture please

Comment: picture and problem explaination added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just replace your  `buttons` position and relation with this

```
<Button
            android:id="@+id/firstButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/genericbutton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstButton" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/firstButton"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/genericbutton" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have a child with alignParenBottom and wrap_content in a RelativeLayout.
Explanation is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content-wt)

One possible solution is to nest LinearLayouts

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/toppane"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/bottompane"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/bottompane"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing your parent Relative layout with vertical Linear layout.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/toppane"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </RelativeLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottompane"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/genericbutton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_above="@id/genericbutton" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/genericbutton"
            android:layout_alignTop="@id/genericbutton" />
    </RelativeLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```