# RelativeLayout takes all its space, even though I've set its height to "wrap_content"

Tags: android, android-layout, alignment, textview, android-relativelayout

### Background

I have a RelativeLayout inside a FrameLayout/RelativeLayout (doesn't matter to me), which should be at the bottom of the screen (like a toolbar), and should hold a few views in it.

Its height is set to "wrap_content" and so does its child-views.

The child-views of this layout are : A textView that is on the left, and a Horizontal LinearLayout on the right with a few buttons.

### The problem

It seems that no matter what I do, the textview is causing the RelativeLayout to take the whole space, instead of just its children.

### The code

Here's the minimal XML content that causes this problem. I've removed the extra stuff (LinearLayout and its children, and also some attributes that don't matter) since they don't cause this problem in case I remove the TextView:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FF000000" >

    <!-- Here I've put some views that don't have any relation with the views below, so it doesn't have anything with do with the problem -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/vertical_gradient_transparent_to_black" >

        <!-- Here I've put a LinearLayout that doesn't cause the problem, so I've removed it for simplicity-->

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I've tried many possible attributes, and also tried adding additional layouts to try to "fool" the RelativeLayout, but none of those have succeeded.

### The question

Why does it occur?

A working solution would be to use a Horizontal LinearLayout (with a weight for the TextView ) instead RelativeLayout , but I still want to know why can't I use a RelativeLayout, and why it occurs. Also how to fix it while still using RelativeLayout.

Comment: Maybe it's because of `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"`

Comment: If you remove  `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>` from `TextView` it should work..

Comment: @user3231871 But if I remove it, the textView will be at the upper area, while I want it to be on the bottom.

Answer (score 4):

From the `RelativeLayout` doc:

> Class Overview
>
> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent.
>
> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. **For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM**

[Class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Which is exactly your case. RelativeLayout can not do that.

Comment: Wow, that's some good sleuthing there!  Of course we've all read that warning, but didn't realize just how easy it is to make this mistake.

Comment: This is a great answer and should be the accepted one!

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue before, this might be caused by `android:layout_alignParentBottom` attribute.Maybe you can find another way to achieve your desired effect. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content) for more information.

Comment: I have found the way - use a LinearLayout instead of RelativeLayout. But the thing is that I just wanted to know why it happens, and maybe fix it without using a LinearLayout.

Comment: Then I recommend you to read the source code of `RelativeLayout`

Comment: why ? Can't a RelativeLayout be used to stay at the bottom, take only the height of its children as needed, instead of taking just the space it needs?

Answer (score 0):

This is some kind of Strange issue. Maybe someone else has the explanation.

I found it working when i removed the line

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
```

and it also worked when i tried some like this

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Comment: yes, but I need it at the bottom. Also, my question is both why it occurs, and how to fix it while using RelativeLayout. I've updated the question in order to explain it more.