# alignParentBottom makes parent height match parent

Tags: android, xml

Here's the problem parent and it's contents from my xml file:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/group_chat_form"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/transparent_background2" >

         <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/send_msg_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/transparent_background2"
        android:text="Send" />

  </RelativeLayout>
```

The parent is clearly not wrapping the contents.

[image]

If I remove the `alignParentBottom="true"` attribute from the child, it looks perfect.
However I need this particular child to stay anchored to the bottom because I have a multiline edittext view in this same parent (I did not include it since this problem still occurs with the multiline edittext commented out). As the edittext expands with more input from the user, the Send button should stay anchored to the bottom of the parent. Here's what it should look like (multi-lined EditText not included):

[image]

Comment: What exactly you want to do? and Why are you putting `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` in `Relative Layout` if it's root tag?

Comment: @Apurva
It's a chat box to type your message in.  The RelativeLayout contains 2 things: A multi-lined EditText and this Send button.  As the EditText view expands with more input from the user, the Send button should stay anchored to the bottom.

Comment: You should create `LinearLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` with only ONE `edittext` and send `button` and on clicking send button whatever text written in edittext should be copied to `listView` of parent layout. And parent layout must have `listView`

Comment: @Apurva There is only 1 edittext.  I said `multi-lined`, not multiple.  How would you keep the Send button aligned to the bottom of a LinearLayout while the EditText inside is expanding?  I tend to stay away from LinearLayouts due to their lack of flexibility.

Comment: First create `RelativeLayout` having `ListView` and `LinearLayout`. Inside `LinearLayout` put one `EditText` and send `Button` `Horizontally`. And as the root layout is `RelativeLayout`, you can align `LinearLayout` to bottom. That's it. Most chat apps use this approach.

Answer (score 3):

That's a limitation for a relative layout. See verified answer in this 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content)

I'm doing the same objective and came up with this solution:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/comment_input_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="@color/light_gray"
    android:padding="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <EditText
            android:id="@id/comment_input_edit_text"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:hint="@string/label_add_a_comment"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences|textMultiLine"
            android:maxLines="6"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

        <Button
            android:id="@id/send_comment_button"
            style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/label_send" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@id/progress_bar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:visibility="gone" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

the `android:layout_weight="1"` causes the editText to take up the free space available as long as the other siblings doesn't have weight.

Hope this helps.