# Aligning an image to the right of RelativeLayout without streatching

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a relative layout that has a background image. I set the height and width to wrap_content. Everything works fine. I want to place an image at the topRight corner of the relative layout. So I use alignParentRight = true. The problem that the relative layout now stretches horizontally to fill the screen.

I have done so much reading and I came across this "circular dependency pitfall"

From the RelativeLayout doc:

> Class Overview
>
> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in
>   relation to each other or to the parent.
>
> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of
>   the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you
>   cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a
>   child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM

Here is my XML sample

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibCloseDialog"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

And that's exactly what I am facing. Is there any recommendation or a way to achieve what I want? I want the the Relativelayout to be as big as the background image and the image at the top right corner of that.

Thank you so much

Comment: use scaletype and set it to matrix

Comment: Maybe a LinearLayout instead of the RelativeLayout. Try it with an invisible (height = 0) View with weight = 1 on the left. That way your ImageButton will be on the right edge.

Comment: possible duplicate of [RelativeLayout is taking fullscreen for wrap\_content](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried setting gravity to `right`?

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:background="@drawable/popup_b"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="right" >


     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/ibCloseDialog"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/close" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I have already faced these problem and i have been solved this way.**

**try this may help u.**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/backGroundimage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/backGroundimage" >
</ImageView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ibCloseDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/backGroundimage"
    android:background="@drawable/ibCloseDialog" >
</ImageView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:background="@drawable/popup_b"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >


 <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ibCloseDialog"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:alignParentRight="true"
    android:src="@drawable/close" />
```

Try using this code.
Here I height and width of RelativeLayout is set to fill_parent.