# Dialog smaller in SDK 23 than SDK 22

Tags: android, android-dialog

I have an app that uses two buttons and a number picker. Everything works fine when running an emulator with SDK 22 but when running SDK 23 the dialog is significantly smaller and does not include the leftmost button.
Here is the xml for the dialog:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" 
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<NumberPicker
    android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="64dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="98dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:text="Cancel" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/numberPicker1"
    android:text="Set" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the code I use to initialize the dialog:

```
final Dialog d = new Dialog(MainActivity.this);
d.setTitle("Delay");
d.setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

Button b1 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button1);
Button b2 = (Button) d.findViewById(R.id.button2);

final NumberPicker np = (NumberPicker) d.findViewById(R.id.numberPicker1);
np.setMaxValue(100);
np.setMinValue(0);
np.setWrapSelectorWheel(false);

b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        changeDelay(np.getValue(), user);
        d.dismiss();
    }
});

b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        d.dismiss();
    }
});

d.show();
```

Comment: Make sure that your two emulators have identical screen characteristics (resolution and emulated density). Beyond that, use Hierarchy Viewer to see where your button is.

Comment: For some reason i cannot get Hierarchy Viewer to run on the emulated device. But the two emulators should have the same screen characteristics they are the same phone just with different software. Im pretty sure the button is not showing because the dialog box is smaller on the sdk 23 phone for some reason but i cant find any reason why.

Answer (score 0):

Try the layout below:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <NumberPicker
        android:id="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="64dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="98dp"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numberPicker1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Set" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Some problems, are:

android:layout_alignBottom will cause the RelativeLayout to expand until the bottom of the screen. This is not good for dialog. You can find details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6486458/4860513)

You defined some huge margins. Your dialog in landscape mode is not displayed properly... Some contents become hidden.

But I'm not sure why it was working fine on API 22 and not on API 23