# RelativeLayout takes fullscreen with layout_height="80dp"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to create a fragment with height of 80dp, and at Design section it seems to work pretty well, but when I run the app on my device, RelativeLayout somehow takes a fullscreen. I use `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` for the SeekBar, but as far as I know it shouldn't take fullscreen if Layout's height isn't `wrap_content`. Here is the XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:background="#bbbbff">

    <SeekBar
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/progressBar"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/playButton"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="play"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:id="@+id/playButton"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT 1: I just tried to use this layout for an activity and it doesn't take fullscreen anymore, but I still have a problem with fragment. Also, I don't change Layout's height programmatically.

EDIT 2: I use `fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.musicBarContainer, musicProgressBar)` to add the fragment to activity, where musicProgressBar is an instance of fragment java class. The musicBarContainer XML code is

```
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/musicBarContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    </FrameLayout>
```

In onCreateView I use `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_progress_bar, null)`;

Comment: xml is just fine . are you changing something programmatically like change   height run time? @Joose

Comment: @Joose check out my answer.

Comment: How do you call your fragment and fragment layout?

Comment: @Ozlem, please check out EDIT 2

Comment: I wrote your code snippets to an empty project, and I did not encounter your problem, i.e., the layout was not full screen in case of fragment. Maybe you miss a point in your code; could you write your whole code so that we can inspect it properly?

Comment: @Ozlem, sure, here it is: http://pastebin.com/CHJs5z5a

Comment: @Ozlem, I just created a new project with code from above and yep, it does still have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MusicProgressBar fragment class, instead of

```
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_progress_bar, null);
```

you should write

```
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.music_progress_bar, container, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

From the `RelativeLayout` doc:

> Class Overview
>
> A Layout where the positions of the children can be described in relation to each other or to the parent.
>
> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. **For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM**

[Class documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

Which is exactly your case. RelativeLayout can not do that.

for more detail visit this answer : [RelativeLayout is taking fullscreen for wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content)

Comment: I guess it's not the case, because layout's height isn't relative here, it's strictly defined as 80dp. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the height of seekbar to 20dp and check. I think its wrap_content is overriding the parents height parameter somehow.