# How to create layout without circular dependencies

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I need advice how to create layout that will show banner(waving lines) with textfield for app version on bottom of app. Something like this
[image]

A managed to create layout like this which is obviously not good beacause it spans on all screen:[image]

because i have circular dependencies there as explained here: [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content)

So i have removed that dependencies
 to accomplish something better:
[image]

Important part of xml is here:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/footer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_devicescreenlogo"
        />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/version"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="5dp"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/textunselected"
        android:text="Version"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FrameLayout` instead `RelativeLayout` in order to get one view on top of another.