# Place a view to the bottom of a relative layout with height wrap_content

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-relativelayout

So I wanted to place a view at the bottom of a relative layout which has height wrap_content.
Did not work at all and I remembered why.... (straight from the [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html))

> Note that you cannot have a circular dependency between the size of the RelativeLayout and the position of its children. For example, you cannot have a RelativeLayout whose height is set to WRAP_CONTENT and a child set to ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM.

It seems like a very simple thing to want to do. Is there a way to hack this and make it work if there is no other view we can bottom align?
I am hoping there is a standard "hack" before actually presenting a specific non-working example which I have tried with LinearLayout and FrameLayout but could not get the end result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, **Put your code first**. From your scenario, It looks like you have declared android:layout_below somewhere that may cause circular dependencies.

Comment: Nothing like that. It is just that the view does not show up properly aligned

Comment: I faced that problem too and it was because of gravity that i set to center to the parent view.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you mean. You had a parent relative layout with height `wrap_content` and a child view with `align_parent_bottom=true` and it worked properly? How can that be? Even the doc say this does *not* work properly (see reference in the post please). In my case the relative layout somehow expands to get its parent's height and the whole layout is "ruined"

Comment: That's just a preview and a layout that has only 1 view. The problem is that the RelativeLayout calculates its height after all the children have positioned themselves and so we can't request for a child to be aligned to the bottom e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content Try adding a few more views and checking it on a device not a preview

Comment: Actually in your photo you reproduced the problem. The relative layout gets the height of the parent but you defined wrap_content