# Wrapping an RelativeLayout around LinearLayouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, layout

I have an `RelativeLayout` and 5 `LinearLayout`s inside the `RelativeLayout`. An `LinearLayout` represents a row of buttons, each `LinearLayout` has 4 buttons, each button has defined width and height.

My problem is that when i set the RelativeLayout's height as `wrap_content` it doesn't wrap the rows of LinearLayout, instead it acts like `fill_parent`.It is interesting that it works to set the RelativeLayout's width as `wrap_content` but not the height.

[image]

```
    <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fifthRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/forthRow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bChangeBase"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bnb"
            android:onClick="onClickBaseChange" />

        <!--- three more buttons --->            

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bP"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bp" />

        <!--- three more buttons --->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b4"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b4"
            android:onClick="onClickB4" />

        <!--- three more buttons --->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/forthRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/thirdRow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b7"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b7"
            android:onClick="onClickB7" />

        <!--- three more buttons --->

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/firstRow"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/b1"
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="85dp"
            android:background="@drawable/b1"
            android:onClick="onClickB1" />

        <!--- three more buttons --->

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Have you considered using GridLayout or a table ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have conflicting layout properties. Your `firstRow` has `android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"` which causes an issue when used with `wrap_content`. Each property tried to rely on the other to determine where the bottom of the view should lay.

More details in the accepted answer here: [RelativeLayout is taking fullscreen for wrap_content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6486214/relativelayout-is-taking-fullscreen-for-wrap-content)

Have you considered using `GridLayout`?